# How to deal with "auth/missing-identifier" error in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I am trying to create a simple web app in node.js (backend only), which would store some user data on Firestore. I want to use my own credentials management, and I believe that `signInWithCustomToken()` should be my ticket to ensure different users can't access each other's data. The problem however is that if I run

```
const firebaseAuth = getAuth(app)
// authToken is a jwt token created by my backent
const response = await signInWithCustomToken(firebaseAuth, authToken)
console.log(response)
```

I keep getting the mysterious `auth/missing-identifier` error, about which I couldn't find anything (it is not identical to `auth/missing-client-identifier` I believe).

Where is the problem? Is my code wrong, or did I set up something incorrectly in the Firebase?

Using `firebase 9.8.1`

Comment: Can you share how you are generating the token? You are using the Admin SDK right?

Comment: I'm using the jsonwebtoken npm package, is that wrong?

Comment: @MilanSmolík How did you overcome this issue? I am currently facing the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error using firebase v9, but I was only getting this error with Facebook login. I switched to use `firebase/compat` methods and it worked for me. It's a temporary fix until more light can be shed on this error. I couldn't find the `auth/missing-identifier` error in any firebase docs so I'm not entirely sure what the underlying issue actually is.

Comment: Can you share your actual solution please? Thanks